# Represent unsigned 12-bit octal numbers. Results in octal

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, mips

I have an HW question where I found an answer that matches mine, but their breakdown confuses me.

Ques: What is 4365 - 3412 when these values represent unsigned 12-bit octal numbers? The result should be written in octal.
I used binary and then looked up the Octal to obtain 753

Found solution: 4365-3412 = 0753
This is because 5-2 = 3 (makes sense), 6-1 = 5 (yep), 8+3-4=7 #we need a carry here, since 3<4 and 4-4=0

I can see where they got 8 (I think) 3+5=8, but why did they do that and how are we getting a carry for the ending of 4-4=0. Appreciate any help/reference.

Comment: `where they got 8` since your base is 8, you have $43_8 = 4 \cdot 8 + 3 = 3 \cdot 8 + (3 + 8)$). I mean, it's the same thing as in base 10: e.g. when computing $53 - 34$, for the last digit you'll compute $10 + 3 - 4 = 9$, and for the first digit: $(5 - 1) - 3 = 1$. `How are we getting a carry for the ending of 4-4=0` - it should be $(4-1)-3=3-3=0$.

Comment: (`3+5=8` did you start adding result digits? Do you do that using a different representation, say, decimal?)

Comment: In this context it's called *borrow*, not *carry*.

Comment: They are using the usual subtraction algorithm. I assume that you know how to subtract numbers in decimal. It is *precisely* the same algorithm, only in a different base.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{matrix}&4&3&6&5\\&\scriptsize\color{green}{-1}&\scriptsize\color{green}{+8}\\-&3&4&1&2\\\hline&0&7&5&3\end{matrix}$$

There is a borrow from the "thousands" to the "hundredths".

Comment: *borrow from the "**hundreds**"  to the "thousands"*

Comment: @greybeard: I wonder. The one is borrowed *from* the thousands and lend *to* the hundreds.

Comment: I'd argue *carries* are from lower significant place to higher, and convention in using *borrow* follows suit here (higher significance place *lending* to lower, lower borrowing *from* higher would be closer to common usage, I guess). But not least, I suggest not to use *hundred**th**s*.

Comment: @greybeard: based on web search, I'll stick to the idea that borrows are left-to-right while carries are right-to-left.

Comment: I may have neglected arithmetic&CS lately compared to electronics design, where *borrow* is just a signal and direction undisputed.

Comment: @greybeard: I have not heard of hardware subtractors so far. Subtraction and negatives are commonly implemented using the two's complement representation, requiring only additions and carries. No borrows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I believe I came to the right conclusion after the responses:
4365 =
4 x 8^3 + 3 x 8^2 + 6 x 8^1 + 5 x 8^0
2048 + 192 + 48 + 5 = 2293

3412 =
3 X 8^3 + 4 x 8^2 + 1 X 8^1 + 2 X 8^0
1536 + 256 + 8 + 2 = 1802

2293-1802 = 491 or OCT 753